# How to format plain text in WPF RichTextBox

Tags: wpf, format, richtextbox, append

I have developed a small chat client using WPF. In each chat window, it contains a richtextbox to display previous chat conversations and a textbox with send button to type a chat message.
I want to format the display text in the richtextbox as shown below.

**user1:** `chat message goes here`

For the time being, I use AppendText function to append chat conversation to the richtextbox. my code looks like this,

```
this.ShowChatConversationsBox.AppendText(from+": "+text);
```

But in this way, i couldn't find a method to format the text as show above. Is there any way to do this? or any alternative methods?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of interacting with the RichTextBox, you can interact with the FlowDocument directly to add rich text.  Set the Document on the RichTextBox to a FlowDocument containing a Paragraph, and add [Inline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.inline.aspx) objects such as [Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.run.aspx) or [Bold](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.bold.aspx) to the Paragraph.  You can format the text by setting properties on the Paragraph or on the Inlines.  For example:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.paragraph = new Paragraph();
    this.ShowChatConversationsBox.Document = new FlowDocument(paragraph);
}

private Paragraph paragraph;

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var from = "user1";
    var text = "chat message goes here";
    paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Bold(new Run(from + ": "))
    {
        Foreground = Brushes.Red
    });
    paragraph.Inlines.Add(text);
    paragraph.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
}
```

Comment: great work. nice! I test this code and it works correctly. This is exactly what i looking for. thank you very much Quartermeister.